# What's the period of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

Consider the matrix
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0.1 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.2 \\
0.2 & 0.4 & 0.0 & 0.4 \\
0.0 & 0.3 & 0.5 & 0.2 \\
0.5 & 0.3 & 0.2 & 0.0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Note since 
$$
A^2  = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0.17 & 0.33 & 0.28 & 0.22 \\
0.30 & 0.34 & 0.16 & 0.20 \\
0.16 & 0.33 & 0.29 & 0.22 \\
0.11 & 0.33 & 0.30 & 0.26
\end{pmatrix},
$$
the matrix $A$ is irreducible, as described in Definition 3 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Classification_of_matrices).  The confusing question now is, what's the period?  Again according to the description linked above, the period of indices 1,2 and 3 is 1, since $(A)_{ii} > 0$ for $i = 1,2,3$.  For index $4$, however, the period should be $2$ since $(A)_{44} = 0$ but $(A^2)_{44} > 0$.  The link then says,
"When A is irreducible, the period of every index is the same..." but I don't see how this is true in this case.  Is the period 1 or 2?  If it's 1, how does that not conflict with index 4's period or 2?  If it's 2, that conflicts with the rest of the indices.

Answer (score 1):

Since all entries of $A^2$ are strictly positive, so are all entries of $A^n$ for all $n > 2$.  The period of index $4$ is the gcd of all $n$ such that $(A^n)_{44} > 0$, so that is $1$, not $2$.

Comment: okay, that makes sense, but it goes against my intuition of 'period' for a Markov chain.  If the matrix $A$ above is the transition matrix for a homogeneous Markov chain, the process cannot return to state $4$  in one step; rather, it can in at earliest 2 steps, right?  So it seems the period of index $4$ should be $2$...

Comment: Your intuition doesn't match the definition.  The period is not the least number of steps the process can take to return, it's the **gcd** of the possible number of steps the process can take to return.  In this case the process can't return in 1 step, but it can return in 2, 3, ....  Since $\gcd(2,3) = 1$, the period is 1.